# Remove internet access from specific applications

Tags: firewall, keepassxc

I'd like to remove internet access from certain applications like KeepassXC.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the snap of keepassxc, you can cut it off from the network:

```bash
snap install keepassxc
snap disconnect keepassxc:network
snap disconnect keepassxc:network-bind
```

I just tested this and launched keepassxc, and it ran fine, but I didn't exhaustively test all the features.

Note that any subsequent update to the application via `snap refresh` (which may happen in the background) may (will) likely re-connect these interfaces. So a workaround for this is to disable updates for this application. That means you get no application or security updates, unless you install them manually yourself.

```bash
snap download keepassxc
snap install ./keepassxc_*.snap --dangerous
```

(The `--dangerous` is to indicate you're happy installing a snap which *may* not have been vetted by the store. In this case it actually was, because you did the `snap download` yourself from the store immediately prior)

Then, proceed to disconnect the network as previously mentioned. By downloading and installing the snap "manually" (so-called "side-loading") this prevents the snap from updating, retaining your network disconnection state.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for...

Is there some sort of GUI firewall that I can see all my applications and set  which one I'd like to have internet access to?

Comment: Yes. There is a piece of software called OpenSnitch which can do this